# Using Try / Except to determine if Model id exists in app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to determine if a model by entity id exists in the datastore;  I'm protecting against a user manipulating the parameter  `/page?page_id=12345` etc.

> ```
>  try:
>      page = Page.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('page_id')))
>  except:
>      self.response.out.write('Invalid page id')
>      return
> ```

Is this an good/acceptable use of Try / Except?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *never* an acceptable reason to use a bare `except`. Always catch *only* the exceptions you're actually prepared to deal with.

However, in this case it's worse than useless. `get_by_id` does not raise an exception, so there is no point catching one. (`int` can raise a `ValueError` of course if the value does not convert to an integer, but you're best off dealing with that separately.) If an entity with that ID does not exist, `get_by_id` simply returns None. You should check for that and act appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.  I'll change the structure to first validate separately for an integer (`isinstance` or `try: y = int(x) except: ValueError` then testing `get_by_id` for None none.

Comment: @DanielYoung for that, the try-except construct is much preferred.